# awk add a column if it doesn't exist

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I would like to add a column 3 (description) if it does not exist in a ';' delimited file. example;

```
#Gene;Transcripts;Description;Group
gene1;G1a,G1b,G1c;gene1 is a good gene;6
gene2;G2a,G2b,G2c;gene2 is a funny gene;3
gene3;G3a,G3b;4
gene4;G4a;gene4 description;5
gene5;G5a,G5b;6
```

Expected output

```
#Gene;Transcripts;Description;Group
gene1;G1a,G1b,G1c;gene1 is a good gene;6
gene2;G2a,G2b,G2c;gene2 is a funny gene;3
gene3;G3a,G3b;No description;4
gene4;G4a;gene4 description;5
gene5;G5a,G5b;No description;6
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slightly different way of looking at this problem might be "if there are not 4 columns of data then move column 3 to column 4 and set column 3 to No description".

This leads to the following code

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN {OFS=";"} NF!=4 {$4=$3; $3="No description"} {print}'
```

Comment: For the sake of completion, why not add an input file for your awk one liner. I know it's obvious to many , but to some other it might not be so. ;-)

Comment: @Cbhihe ... because it might want to be used as a filter in a pipeline?

Comment: minor suggestions: `-F';' 'BEGIN {OFS=";"}` = `'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}` so you don't have to hard-code the separator `;` twice, it's always best to avoid negatives (`!=` in this case) if possible as positives are a bit easier to understand and you can't end up with a double negative if you don't write negatives and `{print}` is idiomatically just `1` so you could write that slightly more concisely as `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NF==3{$4=$3; $3="No description"} 1'`

Answer (score 4):

Using `miller`:

```
$ mlr --nidx --fs ';' put 'if (NF != 4) {$4 = $3; $3 = "No description"}' file
```

This is same approach used in `awk` answer but written in `miller`.

If file's third column is empty as in

```
Gene;Transcripts;Description;Group
gene1;G1a,G1b,G1c;gene1 is a good gene;6
gene2;G2a,G2b,G2c;gene2 is a funny gene;3
gene3;G3a,G3b;;4
gene4;G4a;gene4 description;5
gene5;G5a,G5b;;6
```

Then the following command can be used.

```
# With headers 
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' put 'is_null($Description) {$Description = "No description" }' file 

# Without headers
$ mlr --csv  -N --fs ';' put 'is_null($3) {$3 = "No description"}' file
```

Comment: If you have a varying number of columns, you can still read it as CSV if you use `--ragged`.  For example: `mlr --csv --fs ';' --ragged put 'is_empty($Group) { $Group = $Description; $Description = "No description" }' file`.  Since this creates the missing `Group` field in each record that lacks it, all the resulting records will have the same number of fields.

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` answer given by @Stephen Harris is the best imho. But since `perl` is an option too, therse another couple of ways.

If there are just 2 `;` ( `y/;/;/==2` ) then the third column is missing, so ad the the description `No description`:

```
perl -pe's/(;[^;]+$)/;No description$1/ if y/;/;/==2' data
```

or basically a translation to `perl` of the @Stephen Harris `awk` answer:

```
perl -F'/;/' -spe'$_=join $,,@F[0..1],q^No description^,$F[2] if $#F==2' -- -,=';' data.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness and since the question is tagged `sed` as well, here is a not column-based but rather RegEx based [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) solution (*Notice: this is as good as its RegEx groups are ... So, tweak them as needed*):

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^;]+);([^;]+);([0-9]+)$/\1;\2;No description;\3/' file
#Gene;Transcripts;Description;Group
gene1;G1a,G1b,G1c;gene1 is a good gene;6
gene2;G2a,G2b,G2c;gene2 is a funny gene;3
gene3;G3a,G3b;No description;4
gene4;G4a;gene4 description;5
gene5;G5a,G5b;No description;6
```

Comment: or with fewer capture groups `sed -E 's/^([^;]*;[^;]*;)([^;]*)$/\1No description;\2/'`. I changed the `+`s to `*`s so it'd work even if a field was empty. Alternatively you could use `sed -E 's/^(([^;]*;){2})([^;]*)$/\1No description;\3/'`

Comment: @EdMorton Now that could be what is called RegEx mastery … Excellent tweaking, many thanks … Kuslananda many thanks for the edit.